# How to Order JSON data in the controller using AngularJS $filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I have a data array like below in the controller

```
$scope.sampleArray=[{
    'title': 'SampleTitleOne',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionOne',
    'category': 'Saving'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitleTwo',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionTwo',
    'category': 'Saving'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitle3',
    'description': 'SampleDescription3',
    'category': 'Current'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitleIV',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionIV',
    'category': 'Current'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitleFive',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionFive',
    'category': 'Group'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitleFive',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionFive',
    'category': 'Group'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitleFive',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionFive',
    'category': 'Mixed'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitleFive',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionFive',
    'category': 'Other'
}];
```

I have order the above array based on user input. Suppose user input array is

```
$scope.order = ['Other', 'Group', 'Mixed', 'Saving', 'Current'];
```

After applying the filter the output should be like below

```
$scope.sampleArray=[{
    'title': 'SampleTitleFive',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionFive',
    'category': 'Other'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitleFive',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionFive',
    'category': 'Group'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitleFive',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionFive',
    'category': 'Group'
},

{
    'title': 'SampleTitleFive',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionFive',
    'category': 'Mixed'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitleOne',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionOne',
    'category': 'Saving'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitleTwo',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionTwo',
    'category': 'Saving'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitle3',
    'description': 'SampleDescription3',
    'category': 'Current'
},
{
    'title': 'SampleTitleIV',
    'description': 'SampleDescriptionIV',
    'category': 'Current'
}];
```

Is there any way to apply angular $filter to achieve this?

Comment: You want to order in ng-repeat or only in variable?

Comment: in the variable itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the orderBy filter

```
$scope.sampleArray = $filter('orderBy')($scope.sampleArray, function(item) { return $scope.order.indexOf(item.category);});
```

Comment: Thanks!! How can I filter if I change the $scope.order variable something like $scope.order = ['Other', 'Group', 'Mixed']; in this case scenario, $scope.sampleArray should contain only 'other', 'group' and 'mixed' related records in the array

Comment: then add
$scope.samleArray = $filter('filter')($scope.sampleArray,function(item) { return $scope.order.indexOf(item.category) !== -1; })
before the sorting

Comment: I would do something like
$scope.originalData = [....];
$scope.$watchCollection('order', function(newOrder) {
var filteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.originalData ,function(item) { return $scope.order.indexOf(item.category) !== -1; });
$scope.filteredOrderedData = $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, function(item) { return $scope.order.indexOf(item.category);})
})

Answer (score 0):

You should check orderBy filter and somehow change something in it.